# LocalStack aws lambda invoke fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, localstack

I am trying to use localstack for local aws deployment.

If I try to invoke a lambda via `awslocal invoke lambda` (also tried `aws invoke lambda`), I get the following error response:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "LogResult": "",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

The returned json:

```
{"errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'hello'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError"}
```

Log from localstack:

```
START RequestId: 51521984-63d6-11c3-a25c-c970830bf20e Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 51521984-63d6-11c3-a25c-c970830bf20e
REPORT RequestId: 51521984-63d6-11c3-a25c-c970830bf20e  Init Duration: 212.59 ms        Duration: 2.10 ms       Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 1536 MB    Max Memory Used: 63 MB   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 668, in run_lambda_executor
    result, log_output = self.execute_in_container(
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 1296, in execute_in_container
    return DOCKER_CLIENT.start_container(
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/container_utils/docker_sdk_client.py", line 473, in start_container
    raise ContainerException(
localstack.utils.container_utils.container_client.ContainerException: Docker container returned with exit code 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_api.py", line 444, in run_lambda
    result = LAMBDA_EXECUTOR.execute(
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 495, in execute
    return do_execute()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 485, in do_execute
    return _run(func_arn=func_arn)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 153, in wrapped
    raise e
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 149, in wrapped
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 472, in _run
    raise e
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 468, in _run
    result = self._execute(lambda_function, inv_context)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 791, in _execute
    result = self.run_lambda_executor(lambda_function=lambda_function, inv_context=inv_context)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/localstack_ext/services/awslambda/lambda_extended.py.enc", line 377, in run_lambda_executor
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 713, in run_lambda_executor
    raise InvocationException(
localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors.InvocationException: Lambda process returned with error. Result: {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'hello'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs"}. Output:
2022-11-16T10:58:27.962Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'hello'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'hello'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:726:17)","    at async Object.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:741:21)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:781:15","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:4:1"]}
```

The CdkStack code:

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import * as apiGateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway'

export class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);


    const hello = new lambda.Function(this, 'HelloFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      handler: 'hello.handler',
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lib/lambda')
    })

    new apiGateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 'HelloEndpoint', {
      handler: hello
    })
  }
}
```

and the code for the lambda (in `lib/lambda/hello.ts`):

```
exports.handler = async function(event,  context, callback) {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
        body: 'Hello World from a Lambda'
    }
}
```

`awslocal --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda list-functions` returns the created function.
I already tried to start localstack via `localstack start -d` and with a docker-compose, but nothing helps.

Any suggestions what to do, I already read a lot but found nothing which helped.

EDIT:

I have solved the problem, by renaming my lambda handler file from a .ts to a .js file!